# Svelte: transferring props between parent and child

Tags: javascript, svelte

I've wrote simple Modal component with two `slots` named `button` and `content`:

```
<script>
    let opened = false;

    function open() {
        opened = true;
    }
</script>

<slot name="button" opened={opened} open={open}/>

{#if opened}
    <slot name="content"/>
{/if}
```

Also, `opened` and `open`-method are passed to parent component via `<slot name="button"`

In App.svelte:

```
<script>
    import Modal from './Modal.svelte';
</script>

<Modal let:opened let:open>
    <button slot="button" on:click={open} class:opened>Open</button>
    <div slot="content">Content</div>
</Modal>
```

---

**So, there are two questions:**

1) It looks a little bit weird that props can be passed to parent just through any random slot.

Is it a good practice to do it like this?:

```
<slot opened={opened} open={open}/>

<slot name="button"/>

{#if opened}
    <slot name="content"/>
{/if}
```

2) `<div slot="content">Content</div>` passed with its `<div>`. Could I pass only `Content` without `<div>` or can `Content` be unwrapped somehow?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes it's totally fine. 
Alternative is to use data-binding or events to send info to a parent.

2) You can have a default slot, and it wouldn't need a wrapping element. Example:

```html
<!-- Modal.svelte -->

<!-- named slot -->
<slot name="button"/>

<!-- unnamed/default slot -->
<slot/>
```

```html
<!-- usage -->
<Modal>
  <button slot="button"/>
  I'm unwrapped in the default slot! 
<slot/>
```